# Alter all id´s in a database

Tags: mysql, alter

I have a database whose ID rows are all called "ID". I need to change all of them to "ID_[name of the table"] and change every foreign key relating to those changed ID rows.

Comment: Please replace your `sql` tag with the tag of the DBMS you're using.

Comment: Some support `ALTER TABLE RENAME COLUMN ....` :)

Comment: One question: **Why?**

Comment: @gvee: Probably because somebody told him that it's bad practise to name all pk's `ID`. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/114728/why-is-naming-a-tables-primary-key-column-id-considered-bad-practice (accepted: it is not)

Comment: The database was created by a coworker y we need now to do this change...

Comment: So what database are you using? Oracle? Ms Sql server? MySql?

Comment: MySQL, I edited its tags.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't have been alter all column name in database .

change one by one table column  by using this syntax

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
  RENAME COLUMN old_name to new_name;
```

Comment: Will this change foreign keys too?

Comment: Nope . Drop the foreign key > rename the column> and add the relation

Comment: Would it be possible to do this with a PHP script so that I don´t have to change one by one?